# How to Set Value of Dropdownlist Inside Formview with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, formview

I have some asp textboxes and asp dropdownlists inside an asp.net formview.  I am able use jQuery to set the value of a city textbox with this:

```
$('#<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtMailingAddrCity").ClientID %>').val('Anchorage');
```

However, when I attempt to set the value of a state dropdownlist with this:

```
$('#<%=fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlMailingState").ClientID %>').val('AK');
```

I am getting a null reference exception.  Where am I going wrong?

**Update: Here is the markup**

```
<label class="labelWidth40" for="txtMailingAddrCity">
    City:
</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMailingAddrCity" CssClass="alpha" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("mailingCity") %>' MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="2" />
<label class="labelWidth50" for="ddlMailingState">
    State:
</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailingState" CssClass="stateDDL" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="2" />
```

Comment: Show your markup - the only way you could get a null reference is if `FindControl("ddlMailingState")` is coming up empty. Are you sure that's the right name?

Comment: @bhamlin I added the markup.

Comment: Your both code works fine when formview datasource has something. Both fails if there's no data - which makes sense, no textbox or dropdown exists in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem on the `find` , try using the static id on your control :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailingState" CssClass="stateDDL" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="2"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtMailingAddrCity" CssClass="alpha" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
    Text='<%# Eval("mailingCity") %>' MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="2"/>
```

And set directly on jQuery:

```
$("#ddlMailingState").val("AK");
$("#txtMailingAddrCity").val("Anchorage");
```

Comment: Thanks but that wont work because the control is inside a formview

Answer (score 0):

The exception is probably from empty datasource ( what I found in my test). You need to add an  `EmptyDataTemplete` like below:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <label class="labelWidth40" for="txtMailingAddrCity">
        City:
    </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMailingAddrCity" CssClass="alpha" runat="server"
        Text="" MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="2" />
    <label class="labelWidth50" for="ddlMailingState">
        State:
    </label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMailingState" CssClass="stateDDL" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ValueChanged" TabIndex="2" />
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Comment: the datasource for the dropdownlist is bound in the code-behind, whereas the one for the city is bound in the markup.  Can they mixed like that?

Comment: Yes, you can. In FromView's DataBaound method you can bind the dropdown.